# Increased VGA doesn't fit

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, svg

I wanted to create a Logo (with VGA), so I used Paths to create that form (see Image) but when I increase it, it doesn't fit anymore :(

Does somebody have a fix for that? I have no clue and I am new to this whole SVG thing.

[[image: This is how it looks like before I increase it!]]

[[image: and this after I increased, completely broke[2]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be certain to **Check** `Scale Stroke and Effects` on the **Transform Panel** before scaling.

[image]